# How to add trace file in HNoCs 8x8 Asynchronous mesh topology using OMNET++ tool?

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

How to add trace file in HNoCs 8x8 Asynchronous mesh topology using OMNET++ tool?
I want to attach VoPD application file into this code file also want to attach mapping file of PSO in this configuration file, please let me know how to give path and in which parameter?

`[General]`
`record-eventlog = false`
`**.vector-recording=false`
`network = hnocs.topologies.Mesh`

`# Select Component Types`
`**.routerType = "hnocs.routers.hier.idealRouter"`
`**.coreType   = "hnocs.cores.NI"`
`**.sourceType = "hnocs.cores.sources.PktFifoSrc"`
`**.sinkType   = "hnocs.cores.sinks.InfiniteBWMultiVCSink"`
`**.portType   = "hnocs.routers.hier.Port"`
`**.inPortType = "hnocs.routers.hier.inPort.InPortAsync"`
`**.OPCalcType = "hnocs.routers.hier.opCalc.static.XYOPCalc"`
`**.VCCalcType = "hnocs.routers.hier.vcCalc.free.FLUVCCalc"`
`**.schedType  = "hnocs.routers.hier.sched.wormhole.SchedAsync"`

`sim-time-limit = 2ms`

`# Global Parameters`
`**.numVCs = 2`
`**.flitSize = 4B`
`**.rows = 8`
`**.columns = 8`
`**.statStartTime = 1us # when to start`

`# Source Parameters`
`**.source.pktVC = 0  # the VC injecting the packet on from the NI` 
`**.source.msgLen = 4 # packets per message`
`**.source.pktLen = 8 # in flits`
`**.source.isSynchronous = false # inject flits without any synchronization to clock`
`**.source.isTrace = false  # do not inject based on trace file`
`**.source.fileName = ""    # no trace file given`
`**.source.flitArrivalDelay = 2ns  # 1 flit / Cycle`
`**.source.maxQueuedPkts = 16`
`**.source.dstId = (id + intuniform(1, 63)) % 64 # Uniform random thar prevent self dst`

## Sink Parameters

## all params are global

## In Port Parameters

`**.inPort.collectPerHopWait = true # Controls per hop wait time collection`
`**.inPort.flitsPerVC = 1`
`#**.inPort.sendReqInAdvance = true`

## OPCalc

## No parameters

## VCCalc

## No parameters

## Sched Parameters

`**.sched.arbitration_type = 0 # if 1 allow sending Gnt on next Req while waiting for complted Req Acks`

`if i add trace file path in line sourcefile name with mode true, another error occur.`